# Android : my android app is not sending request header

Tags: android, node.js, request-headers

I'm sending http request with request header with this code:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
Http.post.addHeader("User-Agent",  "Android");
```

I'm trying to get this request header from Node.js by the following method:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
var ua = req.header('user-agent');
console.log(ua);
});
```

But It is showing me that header is unavailable. When I send this request through android browser It gives me complete request header information.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What does `console.log(req.headers)` output?

Comment: The problem has been solved, I was writing 'user-agent' as 'User-Agent'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request header keys are case sensitive so you should write:

```
httpPost.addHeader("user-agent",  "Android");
```